# React useInfiniteQuery - Custom PageNumber

Tags: react-hooks, react-query

I would like to understand how the data.pageParams array works in useInfiniteQuery.

In general we always set a default value to 1. I would like to set a default value as the pagenumber that I receive as props and calculate the next page based on that.

The pageParams array in data always has the value as [undefined, 1, 2, 3...]

If I need to pass the custom page number how should this be done. Can the pageNumber be updated in the pageParams array
Is the pageParam a factor for fetching data from cache?

Answer (score 1):

if you implement `getNextPageParam`, the `pageParam` will always be computed from that function. `pageParams` are only stored in case you use the manual approach - by passing a `pageParam` directly to `fetchNextPage`.

Comment: Thank you.  I have a use case where I  directly load the 5th page and then I need to have the previous pages fetched as well and also the upcoming pages on a scroll. Is it possible ?

Comment: I think you'd need to fetch once with a pageParam to get the 5th page, then use getNextPageParam from there

Comment: How to get the previous pages ? Is there is an option to fetch the previous pages in useInfiniteQuery

Comment: there is `fetchPreviousPage` similar to `fetchNextPage`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. When explored the `fetchPreviousPage` ,it was mentioned that it can be used for normal paginated queries. Will it work for `useInfiniteQuery` as well ?